# Click event Firing twice

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-handling, asplinkbutton

I have the following `LinkButton` in my ASP.NET website:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnUpload" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" OnClick="btnUpload_Click">
    <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span> Upload File
</asp:LinkButton>
```

When the user clicks it, it should get fired once only, but it's getting fired twice.

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How does your codebehind look? Are you sure you don't have the event hooked up there as well?

You have `OnClick="btnUpload_Click"` in your markup which would hook up the event handler once, so if you also have a `btnUpload.Click += btnUpload_Click;` in the codebehind, the event handler would fire twice.

Comment: `Protected Sub btnUpload_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpload.Click`


`End Sub`

Comment: Exactly. See that `Handles btnUpload.Click`? That makes it handle the event twice. Either remove that, or the `OnClick="btnUpload_Click"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `AutoEventWireup="false"` here is example how to use it :
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/324151